# Get max value within an inline view having a TOP clause

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to get the max value within an inline view , but it is returning me the maximum value within the inline view as if the inline view had no TOP clause.

The table dbo.Details in query below contains 650 records. I need to get the max value for top 200 records, but query below gets me the max value over all records in Details table for BatchNumber = 341.

**Is there some subtle point that I am missing? My goal is to get the max value within TOP(200) records.**  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT   MAX(a.DetailsRecordID)  FROM (SELECT TOP(200) npd.DetailsRecordID,    
    npd.BatchNumber  FROM dbo.Details npd WHERE npd.BatchNumber = 341) a
```

Comment: Top 200 based on nothing.  There is no order by.

Comment: Blam - That worked. I ordered the inline view by DetailsRecordID.  Please put your comment into an answer so I may mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top 200 based on nothing. There is no order by.

Even a table with a clustered PK there is no guaranteed order without an order by.

Comment: Blam - You are truly an expert. That thing about table not being ordered even when a primary key is defined is what I discovered in this case. THANKS.

Comment: I only learned by mistakes.   Even with PK you may get it by PK 100 times.  Then you do a join and different set of rows are in cache and then boom you get get a different set of rows.

Comment: Yes, probably because the optimizer chooses the best sort order based on the query's execution plan. So, sometimes you get sort order on PK but at other times it may be based on non-PK column/s.